# find sum of n rows values

Tags: sql, logic

I need get the invoice number which has the particular value in price column, if not all the invoice numbers which have the sum value of that particular value in price column ..how to write an sql query for that

i have attached the data of my table Data

```html
invoice     price
v1         1000      
v2         200       
v3         35        
v4         500       
v5         50        
v6         300       
v7         400
.            .
.            '
.            .
vn          34
```

expected output : if(input 500) found =>then found v4

else(sum of(v2,v6)

**query with multiple join**

```html
select d1.invoice, d1.price,
       (case when d2.invoice <> d1.invoice then d2.invoice end) as invoice2,
       (case when d2.invoice <> d1.invoice then d2.price end) as price2
from data d1 left join
     data d2
     on d1.invoice <= d2.invoice
where (d1.price = 500 and d2.invoice = d1.invoice) or
      (d1.price + d2.price) = 500
```

my current query is not giving dynamic results, suppose the input is 735,so the result should be sum of 3 columns sum of(v2,v3,v4), in that case I have to tweak your query.
can you suggest me a way to dynamic it .thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below logic which will return you all 3 invoice number v2,v4&v6.

> v2 as Price = 500
>
> V4 and v6 for SUM of their price = 500

You can make some changes if the requirement if different. But I this the following logic will help you.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=920b276886f6b53665656845fd667431)

```
SELECT A.invoice
FROM your_table A
CROSS APPLY your_table B
WHERE A.invoice = B.invoice AND A.Price = 500 -- This will check the price as exact input or not
OR (
    A.invoice <> B.invoice AND A.Price + B.Price = 500
    -- This will check sum of 2 different invoice is same as input or not
)
```

Comment: if input 735 then it return empty. but i need the sum of (v2,v3,v4)

Comment: This is considering 2 level only.

Comment: If you have 3 or 4 fixed level, you can easily add more cross apply accordingly. But if you do not know the level for Summing your Price, this logic will not work :(